# REST API and consecutive calls

Tags: firebase

We need to write at several different paths in our base at some point (signup, for instance) and hence are looking for a way to do this directly through the REST API. Yet, to keep it fast enough, we would need to be able to "group" all our update calls: could you imagine that we PUT to "/" with a multi level array { users: { '02943024': { 'name'... } } }

We can surely do this with our own Node proxy, but it sounds like it wouldn't be that complicated to support this kind of grouped call?

Thanks!

Comment: Any particluar reason you're stuck on using the REST API? What language and restrictions are we working in here? What have you tried so far? Have you looked at the [PATCH](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html) command for REST?

Comment: I did use the existing Firebase PHP implementation and it seemed like PATCH could only be used to update a path with a 1 level array. You can't update "/" with an array like { 'users' : { 1: …, 2… }, 'settings': { … } }

Comment: That's true, you can only get one level deep. You're going to have to iterate to perform updates at a deeper level. But probably what you need to do is [denormalize](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html).